# Magento 2: How to create custom ui_component form to submit data by ajax

Tags: php, ajax, magento2, uicomponents

I tried to create a custom ui_component form to submit data by ajax on the frontend. But it didn't appear.

This is the error I got.

> Fatal error: Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function addFieldToFilter() on null in /var/www/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php on line 0

This is my ui-component form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">rentalshipping_form.rentalshipping_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">rentalshipping_form.rentalshipping_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">rentalshipping_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="rentalshipping_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Model\RentalShippingFromProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">rentalshipping_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="employee_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Details</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="employee_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Id</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="employee_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="employee_salary">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Salary</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_salary</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="employee_address">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Address</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_address</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is my dataprovider class:

```
<?php

namespace SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Model;

class RentalShippingFromProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product|null
     */
    protected $_product = null;

    /**
     * @var \SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Helper\ShipmentConfig
     */
    protected $_shipmentConfig;

    /**
     * @var TurnoverByShipment
     */
    protected $_rshippingModel;

    /**
     * RentalShippingFromProvider constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Helper\ShipmentConfig $shipmentConfig
     * @param TurnoverByShipment $rshippingModel
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Helper\ShipmentConfig $shipmentConfig,
        TurnoverByShipment $rshippingModel,
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_shipmentConfig = $shipmentConfig;
        $this->_rshippingModel = $rshippingModel;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: was this ever solved? :)

Comment: I can't solve it, so i go another way :)

Comment: ah no worries :) have a good day ! :D

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue. From what I can see you are missing $this->collection field in your data provider class. For example you could add CollectionFactory in constructor

```
SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Model\ResourceModel\TurnoverByShipment\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
```

and initialize $this->collection

```
$this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
```

So after changes your DataProvider class will look like this:

```
<?php 
namespace SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Model; 
class RentalShippingFromProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider {
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
protected $_coreRegistry;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product|null
 */
protected $_product = null;

/**
 * @var \SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Helper\ShipmentConfig
 */
protected $_shipmentConfig;

/**
 * @var TurnoverByShipment
 */
protected $_rshippingModel;

protected $collection;

/**
 * RentalShippingFromProvider constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
 * @param \SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Helper\ShipmentConfig $shipmentConfig
 * @param TurnoverByShipment $rshippingModel
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $primaryFieldName
 * @param string $requestFieldName
 * @param array $meta
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    \SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Helper\ShipmentConfig $shipmentConfig,
    TurnoverByShipment $rshippingModel,
    \SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Model\ResourceModel\TurnoverByShipment\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    $this->_shipmentConfig = $shipmentConfig;
    $this->_rshippingModel = $rshippingModel;
    $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
}

/**
 * Get data
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getData()
{
    return [];
}
```

}